# Orbits under rational equivalence are countable unions of algebraic subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb C$. Let $x\in X$ be a fixed point.  Let $O_x$ be the orbit of $x$ under rational equivalence, defined as
$$ O_x:=\{y\in X: y\equiv_{rat} x \textrm{ in } X\},$$
where $y\equiv_{rat} x$ means rational equivalence.

It seems to be well-known that $O_x$ is a countable union of algebraic subsets. Could anyone give hints if it is true and why? Any comments or references are welcome.